# Laravel 5.4 - multiple relations in few tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In a picture below we can see relations between my tables.
My target is to get "**type**" from **driver_license_types**. Starting at user object.
For example:

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

and from there I need to get type from driver_license_types. **Important thing** is that instructors can have few records in instructor_license_types table, like this:
[image: Records instructor_license_types]
[image: Relations between my tables]

My current solutions:

- In User model I create method instructor which is relation "belongTo" instructor model.
- in Instructor model I created method license which is relation "hasMany" with Instructor_license_types
- In Instructor_license_types, I create method types which is relation "hasMany" with Driver_license_types.

And final code look like:
[image]

Is there any better solutions?

Comment: Are you not able to use SQL to `LEFT JOIN` the data instead of PHP to sort through the data?

Comment: Why are you creating a new array with both the `id` and `type` instead of just pushing the `type` property in to the array?

Comment: please don't add images for code, how will people edit to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have `belongsToMany` relationship set up in your `Instructor` model for `DriverLicenseType` I would suggest putting one in:

```php
public function licenseTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(DriverLicenseType::class, 'instructors_license_types', 'instructor_id', 'driver_license_type_id');
}
```

```
$user = User::find(1);

$licenseTypes = $user->instructor->licenseTypes->pluck('type')->unique();
```

or if you need the `$licenseTypes` to be in the format you have in your question you could do something like:

```
$licenseTypes = $user->instructor->licenseTypes->map(function ($item) {
    return [$item->id, $item->type];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the driver_license_types directly from the Instructors model by adding this function:

```
//PathToModel\Instructor.php

public function license_types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('PathToModel\LicenseTypes', 'instructors_license_types');
}
```

Also add this to the LicenseType model:

```
//PathToModel\LicenseTypes.php

public function instructors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('PathToModel\Instructors', 'instructors_license_types');
}
```

This way you will be able to remove one of your foreach statements in your code:

```
$user = User::find($id);
if($user->instructor){
    $tmp = [];
    foreach ($user->instructor->license_types as $data) {
        array_push($tmp, [$data->id, $data->type]);
    }
    $user->types = $tmp;
}
```

What this does is just skips over the pivot table (instructos_license_types), for more info on this you can see docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).